# Symfony Add new record by editing

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a possibility to save a new record to database based on existing one?

I'm passing 'id' in url. If it's null, the form with preset name is created and after submit new item is added to database. Edit works the same.

However my goal is to:
1) Pre-populate form with existing data from database (That's why I'm passing id in url to get existing record).
2) Save it as a new record.

Unfortunately my controller is working only like an edit action. Edited data only changes selected item - not saving it as a new one.

Is there a possibility to do this in one controller? How to populate form with existing object from database and save a new record based on previous one?

```
 /**
 * @Route("/form", name="form")
 * @Template("@AppBundle/Resources/views/form.html.twig")
 */
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $itemRecordId = $request->get('id');

    if($itemRecordId == null){
        $item = new Item();
        $item ->setName('Test');
    } else {
        $item = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Item::class)
            ->find($itemRecordId );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item );

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $item = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($item );
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Item created!');
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to pass id, populate the form with Object from the database and then save that object as a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before persisting your Item just clone it, that will unset id and when you save it, it will be a new object.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $item = $form->getData();
    $newItem = clone $item;
    $em->persist(newItem);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Item created!');
}
```

Also, I would think about separating create and edit action.

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am using symfony3.4. this code is working well to me! just edit the form data on editform and click on "save as" button:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Societe $societe) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SocieteType', $societe);
    $editForm->add('saveas', SubmitType::class, ['label' => "Enregister nouveau", 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-success',]]);
   $editForm->handleRequest($request);

   if ($editForm->get('saveas')->isClicked()) {
      $societeNew = clone $societe;
      $em->persist($societeNew);
      $em->flush($societeNew);
      return $this->redirectToRoute('societe_index');
            }

   if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
      $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
      return $this->redirectToRoute('societe_index');
   }

   return $this->render('societe/edit.html.twig', array(
                'societe' => $societe,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            ));
}
```